# How to eager load on different connections in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have 3 database connections. Let's say **con1, con2, con3**.

- con1

  - table1
  - table4
- con2

  - table2
- con3

  - table3

---

Below is a sample of my code. This code does not work and returns the error below. My other relations are working fine so I think the db connection might be the problem. if I remove the eager loading -- ****with(['table4', 'table2'])**** -- it works.

```
table1::with(['table4', 'table2.table3'])
      ->get();
```

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. turns out my code is working. The error just indicates that the data can't be shown in preview because the response is too huge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).